# Understanding the prototype of shared_ptr aliasing constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

Prototype of a shared_ptr aliasing constructor form g++:

```
  template<typename _Yp>
    shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<_Yp>& __r, element_type* __p) noexcept
    : __shared_ptr<_Tp>(__r, __p) { }
```

The example given there is:

```
shared_ptr< pair<int,int> > pii(new pair<int,int>());
shared_ptr<int> pi(pii, &pii->first);
```

That works; has always worked. But looking at the prototype, _Yp is the template parameter that we are providing to instantiate the template and hence the last line above feels like it should should read:

```
shared_ptr<pair> pi(pii, &pii->first);
```

But definitely the example **is** correct. So how do we explain this? I looked at the prototype for the first time today and I am trying to understand how to interpret it.  Thanks for your comments/explanations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing different template parameters/arguments. `_Yp` is *not* the template parameter we are instantiating the `shared_ptr` with. The parameter of the whole `shared_ptr` template in GCC's implementation is called `_Tp`, not `_Yp`. Inside `shared_ptr` that `_Tp` is also known as `element_type`.

Meanwhile, `_Yp` is a parameter of a nested *member template*, which is constructor template.

`shared_ptr` itself and its constructor template are two "orthogonal" templates. `_Tp` and `_Yp` are two independent and unrelated template parameters.

You don't (and can't) explicitly specify the argument for `_Yp`. It will be deduced automatically. But you have to specify the argument for `_Tp`, which is exactly what you see in your example

```
shared_ptr<int> pi(pii, &pii->first);
           ^      ^
           |      |
           |      The `_Yp` parameter is kinda/sorta implicitly present here.
           |      It parametrizes the constructor template. C++ has no syntax
           |      for specifying it explicitly
           |
           This is `_Tp`, not `_Yp`. `_Tp` parametrizes 
           the whole `shared_ptr` template
```

The `_Tp` in this example is specified as `int`, as it should be. The `_Yp` is deduced from `pii` as `pair<int,int>`, exactly as you expected it to be.

Comment: I'm surprised that there appears to be no deduction guide in C++17. However, it is possible to add one: `namespace std 
{
template<typename T, typename Y>
shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<Y> &, T *) -> shared_ptr<T>;
}`

– I have no idea whether this is allowed by the standard or a good idea, though. I have no prior experience with deduction guides.

Answer (score 0):

**Short-Version**

The aliasing constructor can point to an object of any type, so you could create an aliased shared_ptr of any type (in theory). In short, the reference-counting is decoupled from the aliased type.

**Long-Version**

The aliasing constructor creates a new shared_ptr, but re-uses the control block (which holds the allocation information, reference count, etc.). The result of `&pii->first` is `int*`, so it should be a `shared_ptr<int>`, since dereferencing the pointer will return `int&`.

This also means the aliasing constructor has no information about deallocating or allocating the type stored within the aliased pointer, which is precisely why the aliasing constructor can be dangerous: you tell the user it is participates in reference counting, however, there are no explicit guarantees it does so. This may lead to dereferencing freed memory, or memory leaks, and incorrectly elongating the lifetime of the original `shared_ptr`. In this case, the aliasing constructor is used properly (tying the lifetime of a pointer inside the constructed pair to the lifetime of the pair itself), however, caution should be exerted whenever using an aliasing constructor. You should generally use the aliasing constructor to create a pointer to a value inside a collection (like a pair, tuple, array, or struct) to ensure that pointer stays valid for the duration of the new pointer.

An example of where things could go very wrong with using unrelated values is the following example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

using int_pair = std::pair<int, int>;

// Since this aliases a local variable, which goes out-of-scope
// immediately, dereferencing the variable will reference junk memory.
// It will also increment the shared_count of `p`, which may lead
// to a longer lifetime than desired.
// (This is obviously wrong, and that's the point).
std::shared_ptr<int> temporary_reference(std::shared_ptr<int_pair>& p)
{
    int x = 5;
    return std::shared_ptr<int>(p, &x);
}


// Since this aliases a newly allocated variable, this will create a memory
// leak, since `new int(5)` will never be properly deleted.
// It will also increment the shared_count of `p`, which may lead
// to a longer lifetime than desired.
// (This is obviously wrong, and that's the point).
std::shared_ptr<int> memory_leak(std::shared_ptr<int_pair>& p)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<int>(p, new int(5));
}


// This references an internal value in `p` and ties the lifetime
// of `p` to the aliased pointer, to ensure that deleting p
// does not invalidate the aliased pointer.
std::shared_ptr<int> aliased_value(std::shared_ptr<int_pair>& p)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<int>(p, &p->first);
}


int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int_pair> p(new int_pair(5, 3));
    auto i1 = temporary_reference(p);
    auto i2 = memory_leak(p);
    auto i3 = aliased_value(p);
    return 0;
}
```

If we were to use a raw pointer to `&p->first`, rather than an aliased `shared_ptr`, and externally remove the reference to `p`, the pointer may become invalid. Using the aliasing constructor ensures that the internal pointer will be valid for the lifetime of the aliased shared_ptr.

An example of where things could go wrong by using raw pointers is the following example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

using int_pair = std::pair<int, int>;

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int_pair> p(new int_pair(5, 3));
    int& i = p->first;
    p.reset();
    // the reference to i is no longer valid, 
    // since the shared count of the control block of `p` is now 0.
    // if we had used an aliased shared_ptr, it still would be valid

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you mean with *dangerous* and *caution*? Perhaps give an example where things go wrong, even though the code looks innocent enough?

Comment: @Walter Good idea, I added two examples. I'll update to explain caution and dangerous.

Comment: @Walter Is that better?

Comment: Did you mean your first example using a `aliased_value` to be dangerous? The first two examples look stupid and don't appear to be appropriate/intended use of the aliasing constructor. The raw-pointer example does not appear to use the aliasing constructor at all.

Comment: That's the point of the first two examples. They're trivial, but they highlight aliasing objects outside the original container is dangerous. `int main()` is actually a valid entry point for the C++ standard. `int main(void)` should be discouraged (C-like), but `int main()` and `int main(int argc, char **argv)` are all guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: Of course, if you use the *aliasing* constructor w/o aliasing, then you're potentially in trouble. So, yes, you can break your code by doing things w/o knowing what you do. But that's always the case. I'm not convinced by these examples that using the aliasing constructor for aliasing is dangerous.

Comment: Like most things in C++, using them out of context is dangerous and should be used with caution. For example, `strlen` is dangerous and should be used with caution, because it is invalid with arrays without a null-terminator. You should know the limits and reasonable inputs for everything.

Comment: The aliasing constructor, however, significantly differs from the rest of `shared_ptr`, so confusion is somewhat to be expected, so ensuring people know how to use it properly is a good thing. Reasonable caution is always a good thing.

Comment: I don't see how this addresses anything in the question.